# Limit of a separable equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}=k(a-y)(b-y)$$ where $a, b$ and $k$ are constants. Assuming $y(0)=0$:

i) Solve for $y(t)$ when $a=b$

ii) Solve for the case $0<a<b$

iii) By considering the limit $b\to a$ in ii) show that the two results are consistent

My results are $$y=\frac{a^2kt}{1+akt}$$ and $$y=\frac{ab(\exp((b-a)kt)-1)}{b\exp((b-a)kt)-a}$$ respectively for i) and ii)

I'm quite sure these are correct. However the second solution goes to zero as $b\to a$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution does not go to $0$. Let's call $\delta=b-a$, and we'll replace $b$ by $a+\delta$. Also note that we can expand the exponential:
$$\exp(\delta kt)\approx 1+\delta kt$$
Then $$y\approx\frac{a(a+\delta)(1+\delta kt-1)}{(a+\delta)(1+\delta kt)-a}=\frac{a^2\delta kt+a\delta^2kt}{a+a\delta kt+\delta+\delta^2kt-a}$$
Ignore terms in $\delta^2$, and simplify by dividing both numerator and denominator by $\delta$, and you get the answer you need.